# Prevent Text Truncation on JqueryMobile Collapsible

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

How do I prevent a Jquerymobile's collapsible header from truncating text. I have tried

```css
.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-content .ui-collapsible .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn-text {
  white-space: normal;
 }

.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-content .ui-collapsible .ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn-text {
  white-space: normal !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: `.ui-collapsible .ui-btn-text { white-space: normal; }` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/RQFK2/

Comment: That does not work,Note that I am using jquery 1.8 and Jquerymobile 1.3.1, could that be the issue?

Comment: i dont think its the problem, but anyway, use jquery 1.9.1

Comment: Changing to Jquery 1.9 did not help

Comment: there might other classes overriding your css. your code should work.